# Wieso benutzt man "seine Schulden begleichen" nicht "seine Schulden bezahlen"?

Tags: verb-choice

Kann man sagen

> Ich werde nächstes Jahr meine Schulden bezahlen.

anstatt von

> Ich werde nächstes Jahr meine Schulden begleichen.

Comment: The title has another question than in the body. What's your question then?

Comment: Kann man 'seine Schulden bezahlen' anstatt von ' seine Schulden begleichen' verwenden?

Comment: Man kann außerdem seine Schulden tilgen oder seine Verbindlichkeiten egalisieren.

Comment: @Ingo Ein Bänker – äh, Banker – würde das so sagen. Der 08/15-Verschuldete eher nicht. Der **zahlt** seine Schulden **ab**.

Comment: @Em1 Schon klar. Andererseits, wenn er es nicht tut, kann er durchaus "mit der Tilgung nicht hinterher kommen". Wenn man das hört, mag es nützlich sein zu wissen, was "Schulden tilgen" ist.

Comment: why do you keep asking these questions?? There are so extremely many questions you ask, where you throw two sentences at us and ask which one to use. 0 context, 0 research, 0 useful....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, kann man.

a) **bezahlen:** Umgangssprache
b) **begleichen:** Hochdeutsch

Comment: Bezüglich der Kategorisierung bin ich mir nicht so sicher ...

Answer (score 0):

Ich würde behaupten das **begleichen** zum Wortschatz einer bestimmten [Fachsprache](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fachsprache) gehört und man in allen anderen Fällen bzw. Situationen Standardsprache (Hochdeutsch?), also **bezahlen**, verwendet. Sofern nicht ein bestimmter Dialekt oder eine bestimmte Mundart erwartet wird.

> In der Berufsschule hat eine Lehrerin Sprache in 5 sogenannte Sprachebenen eingeteilt (Fachsprache, Standardsprache, Umgangssprache, Mundart und irgendwas hab ich leider vergessen :( ). Wenn ich nach dem Begriff bzw. dieser Einteilung online suche finde ich leider nichts und komme ins Zweifeln.